# for loop in insertion sort

Tags: algorithm

This is about the analysis of insertion sort in the book 'Introduction to Algorithms'. It says that following for loop executes n(=A.length) times:

```
for j = 2 to A.length 
....
```

Can anyone tell me why this loop executes n times rather than n-1 times?

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self:

For the loop for j = 2 to 5

1st iteration: j is set to 2 and the loop condition evaluates to true.

2nd iteration: j is incremented to 3 and the loop condition evaluates to true.

3rd iteration: j is incremented to 4 and the loop condition evaluates to true.

4th iteration: j is incremented to 5 and the loop condition evaluates to true.

5th iteration: j is incremented to 6 and the loop condition evaluates to false and the loop is exited.

So the for statement is executed 5 times although the statements inside the loop are executed 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

While analysing running times for algorithms it is a general practise to round things up. The 1 is not going to make a difference if N is much much larger. Algorithms' analysis are done only for problems whose sample space is huge. What if you want to sort an array that has 2 million integers. Would that one make any difference if the loop runs 1,999,999 times? So be it if the loop runs N-1 times or N+1 times it is N.I hope I make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your book probably says that it executes in `O(n)` time, not `n` times. It probably also contains a chapter (that you may have skipped) on algorithm run-time analysis and on [O-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Long story short, in asymptotic analysis constants don't matter: `O(cn+k) = O(n)`, where `c` and `k` are constants.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean O(N) or does it say it will be only n times. When you get to very large amounts, running one million times or one million minus one can be generalized the same way when estimating running time. Thus something that runs in n-1 times will take roughly as long as something that runs n times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array index is 1-based (AFAIR that book uses this convention) then the loop does execute in n - 1 times. However, in algorithm complexity, for worst case analysis (big-oh) then things are usually rounded up (constant multiplier/adder removed). I believe the book states O(n) instead of n.